# Average costs over custom time range in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I have a table looking like this:

```
ReadingDate,=avg(Cost) 
11/04/2011,£10.00 
28/05/2011,£326.00 
02/06/2011,£12.00 
28/06/2011,£53.00 
10/09/2011,£956.00 
11/10/2011,£63.00 
01/01/2012,£36.00 
11/04/2012,£150.00 
12/05/2012,£100.00
```

I know how to make an avg of a day or month, but how do I make limitations like 'between 01.05.2012 and 11.11.2013' and getting one average from it?

Comment: I was trying to check with if-statement `(if date > myDate, avg(cost))`,

Comment: Also i tried to make group, where i tried to check if date is within my range, but it wasn't working

Comment: My main problem is that i don't know how to sum up all values from one column to one field, which i could later use in my calculations

Comment: @Sagittario Are you trying to do this in the load script, or in a table/chart in the front-end? If it's the load script, do you just need a single value, or a new field?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do this in the load script, you can create a temporary table where you can perform the average over your desired range and then store this in a variable.

I used your source data for the below example:

```
SET DateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY';

MyData:
LOAD * INLINE [
    ReadingDate, Cost
    11/04/2011, 10.00 
    28/05/2011, 26.00 
    02/06/2011, 12.00 
    28/06/2011, 53.00 
    10/09/2011, 956.00 
    11/10/2011, 63.00 
    01/01/2012, 36.00 
    11/04/2012, 150.00 
    12/05/2012, 100.00
];

AverageData:
LOAD
    avg(Cost) as AvgCost
RESIDENT MyData
WHERE (ReadingDate > '28/05/2011') AND (ReadingDate < '01/01/2012');

DROP TABLE AverageData;

LET AverageCost = peek('AvgCost',0,'AverageData');
```

Here, `AverageCost` is your variable and contains a single number (in this case `271`). which you can then use later on in the script, for example:

```
MyData2:
NOCONCATENATE
LOAD
    ReadingDate, 
    Cost
    $(AverageCost)
RESIDENT MyData;
```

This then results in the following:

```
11/04/2011, 10.00, 271
28/05/2011, 26.00, 271 
02/06/2011, 12.00, 271 
28/06/2011, 53.00, 271 
10/09/2011, 956.00, 271 
11/10/2011, 63.00, 271 
01/01/2012, 36.00, 271 
11/04/2012, 150.00, 271 
12/05/2012, 100.00, 271
```